# According to Capacity Insertion

Tags: asp.net-mvc

According to Course's capacity, I want to insert student to Course. If courses capacity overloads it shouldn't insert. What can I do?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here.  These two code samples are nearly identical, they do exactly the same thing and differ only by a single literal scalar value.  What is the actual problem?  What isn't working as expected?

Comment: How can anybody here possibly know?  All this code does is check a `ViewBag` value against a hard-coded value.  If `ViewBag.Capacity` isn't what you expect it to be, then the problem is clearly wherever you *set* that value.  This has nothing to do with "students" or "courses", this is just a simple `==` comparison.  You're going to have to debug your code and determine where the problem is happening, whatever that problem might be.  The code shown in the question isn't it, at least not in this context.

Comment: `if (ModelState.IsValid)` followed by `else if (ModelState.IsValid)` makes no sense - the second `else if` block can never be executed. And having a `ViewBag` property inside a POST method makes even less sense (`ViewBag` is for sending data from a controller to a view)

Comment: What _capacity property_? Its impossible to understand what your problem is

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I have a courses class and capacity is defined here. And my problem is I just trying to according to course's capacity, student should insert to courses. Is it clear?

Comment: No its not clear. You have not even shown your models. Whats is `record` and what do `Course` and `Student` have to do with `record` and What does `ViewBag` have to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code is very wrong. Here is the pseudo code you should have, based on this you can write the c# logic. This seems like a homework problem so I am not going to do part 2 for you.

I am going to make some assumptions here but this is probably what your professor is looking for.

1. check if the model is valid, if not return error otherwise continue. You already have this with `if (ModelState.IsValid)`. You only check it once, not each time.
2. Your model should have the student that wants to register AND the course id they want to register for.
3. Your `DbContext` should have at least 3 models. Students (those users that want to register), Courses (what they can register for), and a relationship between the 2 so you can see what students are registered for what courses.
4. Retrieve the total number of users allowed in the course (capacity) and also the total number of students already registered for the course. Both should be retrieved based on the model's course id. Currently you have this hard coded, it should not be hard coded as it probably varies for each course. You should probably have a `DbSet` named `Courses` on your `DbContext`.
5. If the current total number of registered students for that course is the same as or exceeds the allowed number then return an error. Otherwise add the association record between student and course. If there is no student yet then add that record as well.

Good luck with your homework/project.